# Why does this for loop not go through the whole list ( web scrape)

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

[World cup football results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/71BGE.png)

Could someone please help me work out why I'm only able to retrieve results for Korea vs Germany with this code? Seems like the for loop stops after the first game?

```py
from  bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

source = requests.get('https://www.skysports.com/womens-world-cup-results')
soup = BeautifulSoup(source.text, 'html.parser')


scores = soup.find_all('div', class_='fixres__body')




for score in scores:
   print(score.find('span', class_='matches__item-col matches__participant matches__participant--side1').text)
   print(x.find('span', class_='matches__teamscores-side').text)
   print(x.find('span', class_='matches__teamscores-side').text)
   print(x.find('span', class_='matches__item-col matches__participant matches__participant--side2').text)
```

I'm expecting to retrieve all the game results on that page

Comment: Where do you think `x` comes from here?

Comment: All the `x.find` should presumably be `score.find`

Comment: Yeah should be score.find there

Answer (score 0):

To get all results you need to change how you find scores (change `fixres__body` to `fixeres__item`):

```py
import requests
from  bs4 import BeautifulSoup


source = requests.get("https://www.skysports.com/womens-world-cup-results")
soup = BeautifulSoup(source.text, "html.parser")

scores = soup.find_all("div", class_="fixres__item")  # <-- use fixres__item here


for score in scores:
    t1 = score.find(
        "span",
        class_="matches__item-col matches__participant matches__participant--side1",
    ).get_text(strip=True)

    s1 = score.find("span", class_="matches__teamscores-side").get_text(strip=True)
    s2 = score.find("span", class_="matches__teamscores-side").get_text(strip=True)
    t2 = score.find(
        "span",
        class_="matches__item-col matches__participant matches__participant--side2",
    ).get_text(strip=True)

    print(f"{t1:<30} - {s1:^3}:{s2:^3} - {t2:>30} ")
```

Prints:

```
Korea Republic Women           -  1 : 1  -                  Germany Women 
Morocco Women                  -  1 : 1  -                 Colombia Women 
Argentina Women                -  0 : 0  -                   Sweden Women 
South Africa Women             -  3 : 3  -                    Italy Women 
Jamaica Women                  -  0 : 0  -                   Brazil Women 
Panama Women                   -  3 : 3  -                   France Women 
Portugal Women                 -  0 : 0  -                      USA Women 
Vietnam Women                  -  0 : 0  -                  Holland Women 
China Women                    -  1 : 1  -                  England Women 
Haiti Women                    -  0 : 0  -                  Denmark Women 
Costa Rica Women               -  1 : 1  -                   Zambia Women 
Japan Women                    -  4 : 4  -                    Spain Women 
Canada Women                   -  0 : 0  -                Australia Women 
Republic of Ireland Women      -  0 : 0  -                  Nigeria Women 
Korea Republic Women           -  0 : 0  -                  Morocco Women 
Norway Women                   -  6 : 6  -              Philippines Women 
Switzerland Women              -  0 : 0  -              New Zealand Women 
Germany Women                  -  1 : 1  -                 Colombia Women 
Sweden Women                   -  5 : 5  -                    Italy Women 
France Women                   -  2 : 2  -                   Brazil Women 
Panama Women                   -  0 : 0  -                  Jamaica Women 
Argentina Women                -  2 : 2  -             South Africa Women 
England Women                  -  1 : 1  -                  Denmark Women 
China Women                    -  1 : 1  -                    Haiti Women 
USA Women                      -  1 : 1  -                  Holland Women 
Portugal Women                 -  2 : 2  -                  Vietnam Women 
Australia Women                -  2 : 2  -                  Nigeria Women 
Japan Women                    -  2 : 2  -               Costa Rica Women 
Spain Women                    -  5 : 5  -                   Zambia Women 
Canada Women                   -  2 : 2  -      Republic of Ireland Women 
Colombia Women                 -  2 : 2  -           Korea Republic Women 
New Zealand Women              -  0 : 0  -              Philippines Women 
Switzerland Women              -  0 : 0  -                   Norway Women 
Italy Women                    -  1 : 1  -                Argentina Women 
Germany Women                  -  6 : 6  -                  Morocco Women 
Brazil Women                   -  4 : 4  -                   Panama Women 
Sweden Women                   -  2 : 2  -             South Africa Women 
Holland Women                  -  1 : 1  -                 Portugal Women 
France Women                   -  0 : 0  -                  Jamaica Women 
USA Women                      -  3 : 3  -                  Vietnam Women 
Zambia Women                   -  0 : 0  -                    Japan Women 
England Women                  -  1 : 1  -                    Haiti Women 
Denmark Women                  -  1 : 1  -                    China Women 
Nigeria Women                  -  0 : 0  -                   Canada Women 
Philippines Women              -  0 : 0  -              Switzerland Women 
Spain Women                    -  3 : 3  -               Costa Rica Women 
New Zealand Women              -  1 : 1  -                   Norway Women 
Australia Women                -  1 : 1  -      Republic of Ireland Women
```

Comment: tyvm Andrej! makes sense